# Ceilometer HTTP 404 Not Found

Tags: http-status-code-404, openstack, keystone, ceilometer

I am using pike release of openstack and ceilometer version 2.9.0 and keystone v3. 
$ceilometer meter-list gives HTTP 404 Not Found error
$gnocchi metric list --> HTTP 401 
$openstack metric list ---> lists the meters (works) . However in yaml file(for autoscaling) I am unable to get metrics using type OS:Ceilometer::Alarm

How to go about it, please guide. Is there any workaround for the issue I am facing?